# WPF DataGrid - row for new entry not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The problem is, that the blank row in the DataGrid isn't appearing, ergo user can not add data.
Here is the code:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CoreVocabularyEntry> dataList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CoreVocabularyEntry>();
    public VocabularyToolWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataList.Add(new CoreVocabularyEntry { Foreign = "ja", Native = "ano" });
        ListCollectionView view = new ListCollectionView(dataList);
        WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataList;
        WordsDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;
        MessageBox.Show(view.CanAddNew.ToString());
    }
```

I can't figure out why view.CanAddNew equals false. This looks like a pretty standart scenario, so there's probably something obvions I'm missing. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code ? CoreVocabularyEntry is just the following:

```
public struct CoreVocabularyEntry : IVocabularyEntry
{
    #region IVocabularyEntry Members

    public string Foreign
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Native
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Thx, J.K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `WordsDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;` above the statement where you set the DataGrid's ItemSource.

**EDIT:**

Just noticed you didn't implement [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx).  You'll need to do that for using the editing features of the DataGrid.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work :-(. I think that the problem is is the collection rather then in the DataGrid itself. ( I tries List<T> with the same result.

Comment: Whoops, solved the wrong bug!  Get view.CanAddNew before you set it as the itemssource.  Something about accessing it before associating it with a DataGrid fixed this issue for me.

Comment: You can just use a dummy variable like (bool dummy = view.CanAddNew)

Comment: Really? I just tried it and it didn't fix the issue. Could you copy the code for me? Thx

Comment: See my edit; sorry, I really need to read your code before I start debugging it!!!  (I guess the same applies to my own)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I just implemented it and it's working. I'm one interface smarter again :D

Comment: You do not need to implement IEditableObject. See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVM_DataGrid.aspx

Answer (score 7):

This may be more simple than above.  I had this problem when I did NOT have a default constructor and therefore the datagrid did not know how to add the new row.  My only constructor involved a bunch of information to be supplied.  Go to the object of that the List<> is made from and add a constructor like:
**public MyClass(){}**
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.