# WPF datagrid allow user to add rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm

I would like my WPF Datagrid that is bound to my observable collection to have the blank row at the bottom so that the user can add more info. I've successfully bound the data, i.e. I can see it.

Why is the 'new' blank row not showing? Here is my xaml declaration:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyItems" Source="{Binding Path=AllItems}">
  </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resource>

<my:DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
  CanUserAddRows="True"
  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
  DataContext="{StaticResource MyItems}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

PS: I'm using [Josh Smith's MVVM implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). I have also read some SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466951/wpf-datagrid-blank-row-missing) on the issue and [they](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751897/how-to-get-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid-to-show-new-rows-when-bound-to-dataset) have not [helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579382/wpf-datagrid-row-for-new-entry-not-visible).

Thanks in advance.

**Update 2010-01-14:**

When the usercontrol load event occurs, "CanUserAdddRows" is false. I suspect is has something to do with the conditions listed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found the problem. My constructor in the object that's part of my ObservableCollection wasn't declared public.

*Hits head*

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 28):

Make sure your objects in the ObeservableCollection have a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: And I guess that it is not possible with a collection of an interface type.. (?)

Comment: Sometimes one sentence is enough :)

Answer (score 5):

The new blank row will depend if the collection you are binding implements IEditableCollectionView. see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/20/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-ieditablecollectionview.aspx). That being said i have found that sometimes it works well and other times unexplainably it seems not to, but the IEditableCollectionView is a start

Comment: According to the link you presented, ObservableCollection already implements IEditableCollectionView. At least that's how interpreted it.

Comment: Although, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx it does not. Thanks for the tip.