# WPF DataGrid How to add a blank row when binding to an interface

Tags: wpf, datagrid, interface

I am trying to set up a DataGrid to have a blank row at the end, by making use of `CanUserAddRows="True"`

The same sort of thing is answered in multiple other questions such as [WPF datagrid allow user to add rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060046/wpf-datagrid-allow-user-to-add-rows) and [WPF DataGrid: Blank Row Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466951/wpf-datagrid-blank-row-missing)

One of the key points mentioned in answers to both of those questions was

> Make sure your objects in the ObeservableCollection have a default
>   parameterless constructor.

But this is where I have a problem.  The collection I am binding to is defined thus:

```
public ObservableCollection<IDataItem> ItemList { get; }
```

So of course I can't define a parameterless constructor, as I am binding to an interface.  So how can I do this?

I know that if bind to a collection of concrete objects then it all works.

And FWIW I am trying to use IOC (for the first time) through a `UnityContainer`, so any answers that work through `Resolve<IDataItem>()` are welcome.

**Final Code**

I took Johan's answer and rolled in my own IOC container ideas by making a singleton factory for the UnityContainer.  This led to code that looks like (using Johan's code)

```
void RegisterTypes()
{
   IUnityContainer container = UnityFactory.Instance.Container;
   container.RegisterType<IDataItem, DataItem >(new InjectionConstructor());
}

..

private readonly BindingList<IDataItem> _itemList = new BindingList<IDataItem>();

public ViewModel()
{
    _itemList.AllowNew = true;
    IUnityContainer container = UnityFactory.Instance.Container;
    _itemList.AddingNew += (sender, e) => { e.NewObject = container.Resolve<IDataItem>(); };

}

public BindingList<IDataItem> ItemList
{
    get { return _itemList; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer has what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484256/how-to-use-a-factory-for-datagrid-canuseraddrows-true) i.e:

```
    private readonly BindingList<IDataItem> _itemList = new BindingList<IDataItem>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _itemList.AllowNew = true;
        _itemList.AddingNew += (sender, e) => e.NewObject = new DataItem(...); 
        // I don't think you want to show your IoC here
    }

    public BindingList<IDataItem> ItemList
    {
        get { return _itemList; }
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want!  Also see my edits for where I put my IOC container.